Custom Post Type Taxonomy Filter is Not Working in Admin Dashboard
I have added a custom post type called movies to my WordPress site, along with a custom taxonomy called genres. The end goal was to enable filtering of movies based on genres in the WordPress admin dashboard, but my filter isn't working quite right and, on choosing a value from the dropdown filter, nothing changes on the page they all appear as all the movies.
Components that i was using :

Custom Post Type: movies

Custom Taxonomy: genres

Filter Hook: I was adding the genre filter in the admin movies list by using the restrict_manage_posts action.

Query Modification: After that am modifying the admin query with pre_get_posts to add the genre filter.


Registration of the Custom Post Type and Taxonomy
function register_movies_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Movies',
        'singular_name'      => 'Movie',
        'menu_name'          => 'Movies',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Movie',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Movie',
        'new_item'           => 'New Movie',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Movie',
        'view_item'          => 'View Movie',
        'all_items'          => 'All Movies',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Movies',
        'not_found'          => 'No movies found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No movies found in Trash.',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies'         => array('genres'), // Associate genres taxonomy
    );

    register_post_type('movies', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_movies_post_type');

function create_movies_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Genres',
        'singular_name'     => 'Genre',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Genres',
        'all_items'         => 'All Genres',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Genre',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Genre',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Genre',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Genre Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Genres',
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // like categories
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'genre'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('genres', array('movies'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_movies_taxonomy');


2. Adding the Genre Filter to Admin Dashboard:

function filter_movies_by_genre() {
    global $typenow;

    if ($typenow == 'movies') {
        $taxonomy = 'genres';
        $genres = get_terms($taxonomy);
        
        if ($genres) {
            echo '<select name="genres" id="genres" class="postform">';
            echo '<option value="">Show All Genres</option>';
            foreach ($genres as $genre) {
                $selected = (isset($_GET['genres']) && $_GET['genres'] == $genre->slug) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($genre->slug) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html($genre->name) . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_movies_by_genre');


3. Modifying the Query by Changing the Filtering Criteria:

function filter_movies_by_genre_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

    if ($post_type == 'movies' && is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['genres']) && $_GET['genres'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $_GET['genres'],
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_movies_by_genre_in_query');

Even after putting the filter dropdown, when modifying the query, the filtering does not work. If i select a genre and click on the filter button, the list of movies does not change; no filtering is done based on the selected genre.

try this code as its working I have checked.
function movies_post_type_filter_by_taxonomy()
    {
        global $typenow;
        $post_type = 'movies';
    
        if ($typenow == $post_type) {
            $taxonomies = array('genre');
            foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
                $selected = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
                $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
                wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' => __("Show All {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'name' => $taxonomy,
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'selected' => $selected,
                    'show_count' => false,
                    'hide_empty' => true,
                ));
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'movies_post_type_filter_by_taxonomy');
    
    function movies_post_type_filtering_by_taxonomy($query)
    {
        global $pagenow;
        $post_type = 'movies';
        $taxonomies = array('genre');
    
        if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $query->get('post_type') == $post_type) {
            foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
                if (isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) && $_GET[$taxonomy] != '') {
                    $term_id = intval($_GET[$taxonomy]);
                    if ($term_id > 0) {
                        $term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
                        if ($term) {
                            $query->query_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    add_filter('parse_query', 'movies_post_type_filtering_by_taxonomy');

